# Aurelia child router - use case

Tags: aurelia

I have been doing some initial work to get to grips with the Aurelia framework and am trying to decide if I should be using child routers. This doesn't seem to be covered in much detail on the [Aurelia router configuration page](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration).
I was wondering if anyone has come across any good use case scenarios that I could examine to get a better understand of where and when to use this feature.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario that springs to mind is 2nd level navigation. Say, for example, you have a main router for the top level sections of your app, eg:

- Home
- Products

Those sections could have a child router to handle the 2nd level pages - eg:

- Products

  - Aircraft
  - Bombs
  - Guns
  - Tanks

Having the sub-views (aircraft, bombs, etc) for the products view in their own child router allows you to easily build out 2nd level navigation.

Comment: Thanks, that was one of the things I was mulling over. I guess the top level app router will be checked first for a matching route and if there is no match pass to the child levels..